# Sanity CMS, using type "object" as reference

Tags: sanity

Is it not possible to use an object type as a reference in sanity? For example this is not working. When I go to the field nothing shows up. If I can't do this how can I access the indexPage objects that have been created under other documents?

```js
export const indexPage = {
  title: "Index Page",
  name: "indexPage",
  type: "object",
  fields: [
    {
      title: "Subheading",
      name: "subheading",
      type: "array",
      of: [{ type: 'block' }] 
    },
    {
      title: "Content",
      name: "content",
      type: "array",
      of: [{ type: "block" }]
    },
  ]
}

// in another file

export const coolPage = {
  title: "Cool Page",
  name: "coolPage",
  type: "object",
  fields: [
    {
      title: "Reference Index Page",
      name: "refIndexPage",
      type: "reference",
      to: [{ type: 'indexPage' }] 
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

References can only point to other documents; not to a specific *part* of a document. So to achieve this, `indexPage` would need to be a document.

I think modelling `indexPage` as a document would be a viable option in your case. You mentioned "indexPage objects that have been created under other documents". Instead of creating `indexPage` data inside a specific document, `indexPage` should be its own document type. Any other document can then connect to it via a reference. This approach should be really flexible for you.

Sanity Studio recently added support for "references in place", which makes this workflow even better. The studio now allows you to create a document to reference *while* you are editing the document that references it—without leaving the editor. You can [see a demo here](https://www.sanity.io/blog/recap-a-sanity-open-house-on-delightful-editorial-experiences#cddc9e16abe1) (no extra work on your part is needed here, it's handled automatically by Sanity Studio).

In summary: if you have a piece of data you'd like to share between multiple documents, model it as its own document type that is referenced by every document that is related.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach is to make another query based on references from the parent document:

```
*[_type == "page"] {
  "breadcrumbs": *[_type == "page" && _id in ^.breadcrumbs[]._ref] {
    seo_title,
    "slug": slug.current,
  }
}
```

Result:

```json
"breadcrumbs": [
  {
    "seo_title": "Company",
    "slug": "company"
  },
  {
    "seo_title": "Home",
    "slug": "home"
  }
]
```

In this example, we consult the `seo_title` and the `slug` of a page, checking whether its `_id` is in the array with references to the 'bradcrumbs' property that is in the parent document.

Another informations on Sanity documentation: https://www.sanity.io/docs/how-queries-work#52023b22ca05.